# How could I change a Boolean field to show a value like Up = true or Down = False in a serialized field in Django

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have a serialized data set in Django Rest Framework to be consumed, but I have a question that I want to solve, there is a field that is Boolean, and clearly when I serialize it shows two values: true or false, the question is that I do not want show these values, I want to show UP = True, DOWN = False

These fields in question are: status and ospf

My Model

```
class Interfaces(models.Model):

    id_interface = models.PositiveIntegerField(primary_key=True)
    id_EquipoOrigen = models.ForeignKey(Equipos, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, related_name='equipo_origen')
    id_PuertoOrigen = models.ForeignKey(Puertos, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, related_name='puerto_origen', null=True, blank=True)
    estatus = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    etiqueta_prtg = models.CharField(max_length=80, null=True, blank=True)
    grupo = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(default=0, blank=True)
    if_index = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0, blank=True)
    bw = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(default=0, blank=True)
    bw_al = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(default=0, blank=True)
    id_prtg = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(default=0, blank=True)
    ospf = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    id_EquipoDestino = models.ForeignKey(Equipos, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, related_name='equipo_destino')
    id_PuertoDestino = models.ForeignKey(Puertos, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, related_name='puerto_destino')
    ultima_actualizacion = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

My Serializers Model Interfaces

```
class InterfaceSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    EquipoOrigen = serializers.CharField(source='id_EquipoOrigen.nombre',read_only=True)
    PuertoOrigen = serializers.CharField(source='id_PuertoOrigen.nombre',read_only=True)
    LocalidadOrigen=serializers.CharField(source='id_EquipoOrigen.localidad',read_only=True)
    CategoriaOrigen=serializers.CharField(source='id_EquipoOrigen.categoria',read_only=True)
    EquipoDestino = serializers.CharField(source='id_EquipoDestino.nombre',read_only=True)
    PuertoDestino = serializers.CharField(source='id_PuertoDestino.nombre',read_only=True)
    LocalidadDestino=serializers.CharField(source='id_EquipoDestino.localidad',read_only=True)
    CategoriaDestino=serializers.CharField(source='id_EquipoDestino.categoria',read_only=True)
    Vendedor=serializers.CharField(source='id_EquipoOrigen.vendedor',read_only=True)

    class Meta:

        model=Interfaces
        fields=('id_interface','id_EquipoOrigen','EquipoOrigen','id_PuertoOrigen','PuertoOrigen','LocalidadOrigen','CategoriaOrigen','Vendedor','estatus','etiqueta_prtg','grupo','if_index','bw','bw_al','id_prtg','ospf','description','id_EquipoDestino','EquipoDestino','id_PuertoDestino','PuertoDestino','LocalidadDestino','CategoriaDestino','ultima_actualizacion',)
```

```
class InterfacesViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):


    queryset = Interfaces.objects.all()
    serializer_class = InterfaceSerializer
    pagination_class = PostPageNumberPagination
    filter_class = InterfacesFilter
```

[image]

Comment: Do you only want to retrieve data, or post data as well?

Comment: At the moment I wish that these changes be published, but I would like to learn both ways

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [SerializerMethodField](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#serializermethodfield) for that

```
class InterfaceSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

estatus = serializers.SerializerMethodField(method_name='conversion_bool')
EquipoOrigen = serializers.CharField(source='id_EquipoOrigen.nombre',read_only=True)
PuertoOrigen = serializers.CharField(source='id_PuertoOrigen.nombre',read_only=True)
LocalidadOrigen=serializers.CharField(source='id_EquipoOrigen.localidad',read_only=True)
CategoriaOrigen=serializers.CharField(source='id_EquipoOrigen.categoria',read_only=True)
EquipoDestino = serializers.CharField(source='id_EquipoDestino.nombre',read_only=True)
PuertoDestino = serializers.CharField(source='id_PuertoDestino.nombre',read_only=True)
LocalidadDestino=serializers.CharField(source='id_EquipoDestino.localidad',read_only=True)
CategoriaDestino=serializers.CharField(source='id_EquipoDestino.categoria',read_only=True)
Vendedor=serializers.CharField(source='id_EquipoOrigen.vendedor',read_only=True)

class Meta:

    model=Interfaces
    fields=('id_interface','id_EquipoOrigen','EquipoOrigen','id_PuertoOrigen','PuertoOrigen',
            'LocalidadOrigen','CategoriaOrigen','Vendedor','estatus','etiqueta_prtg','grupo',
            'if_index','bw','bw_al','id_prtg','ospf','description','id_EquipoDestino',
            'EquipoDestino','id_PuertoDestino','PuertoDestino','LocalidadDestino','CategoriaDestino',
            'ultima_actualizacion',)

def conversion_bool(self, instance):
    if instance.estatus == True:
        return "Up"
    else:
        return "Down"
```

Like this you can do for any other field.

Comment: This worked for me only for reading, I would also like to achieve it for editing. Thank you so much

Comment: to be able to make a PUT with that representation, so that by modifying the representation the changes in the Boolean values ​​will also be realized. You understand me?

Answer (score 1):

The quick and read-only way is to use a [SerializerMethodField](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#serializermethodfield).

The most complete way which supports read / write is to create a custom [SerializerField](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#examples). Override `to_representation` and `to_internal_value` to handle the translation between boolean and your custom representation.

Comment: Is there no way to do it specifically for a queryset?, Since it is necessary for an Excel record download only

Comment: I don't understand... you were asking about Django Rest Framework serializers, why is Excel involved now?

Comment: Do not pay attention to the Excel, just tell me if there is the possibility of doing the above mentioned in a queryset, or failing that as would be done with the mentioned properties, since the truth is that the documentation does not understand much

Comment: Sorry, but I still don't understand what you're asking... what do you mean "in a queryset"? The serializer is the correct place to adjust how a queryset is translated to JSON format.

Comment: Friend, we are going to leave it in that I want to serialize it as a custom representation, but I would like it to support reading / writing, since I was reading the DRF documentation but I did not understand the properties to_representationy to_internal_value